# How to create ElementMap without entry?

Tags: java, android, simple-framework

I need serialize Map object like this with simlexml:

```
<attributes>
   <name>name1</name>
   <value>value1</value>
   <name>name2</name>
   <value>value2</value>
   <name>name3</name>
   <value>value3</value>
</attributes>
```

I tried this:

```
@ElementMap(name = "attributes", key = "name", value = "value", inline = true, required = false)
private HashMap<String, String> attributes;
```

But result looks like:

```
   <entry>
      <name>name1</name>
      <value>value1</value>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      <name>name2</name>
      <value>value2</value>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      <name>name3</name>
      <value>value3</value>
   </entry>
```

Is this possible to create element that i need using simplexml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As *runefist* noted, the entry tag will get generated for this type. But what you can do: Customize the (de-)serialization process by using a [**`Converter`**](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/convert/Converter.html).

Here's an example class for serialization:

```
@Root(name = "Example")
public class Example
{
    @Element
    @Convert(ExampleConverter.class)
    private HashMap<String, String> attributes; // Will use the Converter instead

    // ...

    public static class ExampleConverter implements Converter<HashMap<String, String>>
    {
        @Override
        public HashMap<String, String> read(InputNode node) throws Exception
        {
            // Implement if needed
        }


        @Override
        public void write(OutputNode node, HashMap<String, String> value) throws Exception
        {
            value.forEach((k, v) -> {
                try
                {
                    node.getChild("name").setValue(k);
                    node.getChild("value").setValue(v);
                }
                catch( Exception ex )
                {
                    // Handle Error
                }
            });
        }

    }
}
```

If you also need to deserialize your class, you only have to implement the `read()` method.

Finally, don't forget to enable the `AnnotationStrategy`:

```
Serializer ser = new Persister(new AnnotationStrategy());
                               //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This will generate following output:

```
<Example>
   <attributes>
      <name>name2</name>
      <value>value2</value>
      <name>name1</name>
      <value>value1</value>
      <name>name0</name>
      <value>value0</value>
   </attributes>
</Example>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, XML needs the  tag to see what part is an element.
But... what's the problem with it having the  tags?